# Org-mode results verbatim not working for Scheme code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, scheme

I have the following source block of Scheme code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :results value verbatim append
(define shift
  (lambda (list-with-sublists)
    (cond
     [(pair? (car list-with-sublists))
      (cons (car (car list-with-sublists))
            (cons (cdr (car list-with-sublists))
                  (cdr list-with-sublists)))]
     [else
      (cons (car list-with-sublists)
            (cdr list-with-sublists))])))

(shift '(a (b c) d))
#+END_SRC
```

However, it seems that org-mode cannot resist formatting the resulting list as a table and it will output tables, disregarding the `verbatim` argument:

```
#+RESULTS:
| a | (b c) | d |
| a | (b c) | d |
| a | (b c) | d |
```

I have tried it with `silent` and in the minibuffer the output is only a string `(a (b c) d)`. So I went ahead and tried to output the same string in Python, to see, whether it is programming language related:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output verbatim replace
print("(a (b c) d)")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (a (b c) d)
```

This works just fine. `verbatim` only does not work for my Scheme code.

What am I doing wrong?

## Versions

- Emacs: `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.0)
  of 2018-11-14`
- Org-mode: `9.1.9` (built-in)

## Edit

By now I have figured out, that I can get a string output, but only, if I format the Scheme value as a string already in my code. Probably the issue is, that Org-babel does not know how to deal with arbitrary values from any programming language.